# Unwanted characters showing on the button next to the image

Tags: swift, xib, xcode14

The button is set to a system image "plus" without any title, but somehow it displays, I guess, "Button" next to it. Any idea?

I'm on Xcode 14.2.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened the XIB in the text editor and removed this line associated with the "+" button and now the text is gone from UI.

`<state key="normal" title="Button"/>`

Xcode is such a garbage IDE...